# The ProjectGuid and ModelGuid is not shown in the return from API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to obtain the ProjectGuid and ModelGuid to open the cloud model. I followed this [link](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-bim-360-design-models-revit) and used the projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/versions. However the return doesn't give me the modelGuid and projectGuid. See the below snip:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERcDl.png)

And the example in this documentation also doesn't have the Guid returned.

Any suggestion will be appreciated?

I want get the projectGuid and modelGuid of the model in ACC/BIM360